# How can I install module PDF::OCR2 in perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, module, ocr

I am trying to fetch text from scanned PDF using perl, so I use PDF::OCR2 module in perl but I can not install this module,it is fail at installation of Image::OCR::Tesseract module, I am using CentOS7,here is my error during installation

```
one dependency not OK (Image::OCR::Tesseract); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports LEOCHARRE/PDF-OCR2-1.21.tar.gz
Running make install
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/perllocal.pod
  LEOCHARRE/PDF-OCR2-1.21.tar.gz
  sudo /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
Failed during this command:
 LEOCHARRE/PDF-OCR2-1.21.tar.gz  : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Image::OCR::Tesseract); additionally test harness failed
```

I read it's installation guid,they suggested to install gcc-c++ and automake first and then run following commands

```
 svn checkout http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tesseract-ocr
 ./runautoconf
 mkdir build-directory
 cd build-directory
 ../configure
 make
 make install
```

but it's url does not work
Is there any other way to install the module PDF::OCR2 successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract, like many things has moved to github:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr

You need to clone and build this software from here before trying to install the [PDF::OCR2](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PDF-OCR2/lib/PDF/OCR2.pod) module. Submit a ticket or a patch to update the INSTALL instructions.

Comment: it's not work, it checkout successfully but another steps not works, means  ./runautoconf give error: bash: ./runautoconf: No such file or directory,i think it is another way to proceed further,Do you know that way?

Comment: You aren't reading the installation notes from the link I gave you. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling if you want to use software please at least read the documentation that it comes with. The perl module you're using has not been updated in 5 years, consider that you'll have to do some research here, or at least follow the links you're given and read what's there.